# Retrofit Multiple POST Request

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm new using this library and tried it in some of rest API in our project and its performs great.

Now I'm trying to create a POST request inside a loop base on the ArrayList items , is it possible ? or is there a nicer way doing it ?.

Here are some of my code to help you understand what im a thinking

MContacts.tk

```
  data class MContacts(val name:Sting,val contact:String,val address:String){ 
    companion object {
      val name = "name"
      val contact = "contact"
      val address = "address"
    }
  }
```

ApiUtils

```
object ApiUtils {
    val BASE_URL = "http://api.link.com/"
    fun getSOService(): ApiService {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient

```
object RetrofitClient {

    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }
}
```

ApiService

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("api/postcontact")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun postContact(
            @Field("name") name:String,
            @Field("contact") contact:String
            @Field("address") address:String
            )
            :Call<ContactResponse>
}
```

Activity

```
var listContacts : ArrayList<MContacts> = ArrayList()
var btnPost:Button? = null
private var mService: ApiService? = null

override fun onCreate(..){


   mService = ApiUtils.getSOService()

   btnPost = find<Button>(R.id.btnPost)

   listContacts.add(MContacts("name-abc","98765632","address 1"))
   listContacts.add(MContacts("name-ab1","9876562","address 2"))
   listContacts.add(MContacts("name-bs","9876465","address 3"))
   listContacts.add(MContacts("name-df","98876356","address 4"))
   listContacts.add(MContacts("name-da","9876533","address 5"))


   btnPost.setOnClickListener{
      //in here my question begins on how can i post all of the listContacts items
      // is ok to make just make a loop of post request like this ?

      for(i in 0 until listContacts.size){
       postnow(
              listContacts.get(i).name,
              listContacts.get(i).contact,
              listContacts.get(i).address )
      }

   } 
}
```

POST function

```
fun postnow(name:String,contact:String,address:String){

   mService!!.postContact(  name ,  contact,   address  ).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
              override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {

               if (response.isSuccessful()) { 

               } else {

               }
            }

              override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                   Log.d("app", "error loading from API")
                 }
            })
}
```

Thanks for your time helping. giving your correction, comment and suggestion

Comment: Yes. Possible. Nicer way would include RX, or Executors.

Comment: Thank for replying can you give me some snippet and where should i put it.